# running eslint on github repos through api

Tags: api, github, architecture, graphql, eslint

I am working on multiple projects, i.e. multiple repos on github and have more than 10 repositories with multiple people contributing to different repos on daily basis.

It was getting hard to manage various aspects of repos, so I decided to build a dashboard using github graphql api, to visualize and display 
 summary on one page.

I want to show status for each repo, if eslint passed or not. Currently I am in dilemma on how to run eslint on each repository progamatically, and report the errors and warnings on one page using some api,

I did setup a node-graphql project and getting various information from the repos. Not really sure how to approach for this particular feature.Any help or suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The generally practiced approach is to setup eslint as a precommit hook on the repositories. This will ensure that only linted code is pushed to the repo. I didn't understood your use case of running this as a post process and displaying the errors.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I almost gave up on this. use case:- to get a high level view of the repositories if they are eslint compliant or not, sometimes team does are not compliant with linting the code before pushing it, and it keeps on going.